# Fixating Elements in Place Despite Change in Content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my elements to stay in place. When clicked, the temperature unit changes (celsius/fahrenheit).

Switching between two digits works neatly (Seoul in image). But when switching from two digits to a single digit, the elements shift to the left (Paris in image). This is probably because I have set `justify-content: flex-start`. But even if I set `justify-content: center`, the elements don't stay perfectly in their place. They move a bit.

**I wish to place the big temperature number in the center always. And want to switch between the degree units in their exact position (to make the shift look neater).**

I've tried `space-between` and other `justify-content` values. I've also tried placing margins to have consistent buffer between the elements.

**These are images of what's happening:**

[Fahrenheit Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urUvp.png)

[Celsius Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSg5P.png)

**This is my code:**

```css
.info {
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.temp_container {
  width: 130px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 200ms ease-out;
}

.temp_container:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.712);
}

.min_max {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.max {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.temp {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.temp_degree {
  font-size: 3.4rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.temp_unit {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="location">
    <h2 class="timezone">Timezone</h2>
    <div class="weatherIcon"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="info">
    <div class="temp_container">
      <div class="min_max">
        <span class="max"></span>
        <span class="min"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="temp">
        <h2 class="temp_degree"></h2>
        <span class="temp_unit"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="temp_desc"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share your css code aswell? it will be easier for us to help

Comment: Oh right. Just added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because the `h2` width changes when content is changed. In the below example, a static width is set to the `.temp_degree`.

Changes from your code: last 2 lines in `.temp_degree` selector.

```css
.info {
    height: 70%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.temp_container {
    width: 130px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 200ms ease-out;
}
.temp_container:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.712);
}
.min_max {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.max {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.temp {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}
.temp_degree {
    font-size: 3.4rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-right: 2px;
    width: 4rem;
    text-align: right;
}
.temp_unit {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
            <div class="location">
                <h2 class="timezone">Timezone</h2>
                <div class="weatherIcon"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="info">
                <div class="temp_container">
                    <div class="min_max">
                        <span class="max"></span>
                        <span class="min"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="temp">
                        <h2 class="temp_degree">10</h2>
                        <span class="temp_unit">℃</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="temp_desc"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It looks much much better. But it doesn't seem to be perfectly in place. For example, the degree symbol (°) should stay in the exact same spot but it moves a little.

Comment: Are you able to post a more reproducible snippet to work on? The current snippet only shows the text with nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for helping me but I just figured it out. I kept your inclusion, and got rid of the width on my `.temp_container`, and set widths for all the children inside.